# Is there any official CKEditor for Laravel?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have seen a official CKFinder for Laravel ([Source](https://ckeditor.com/blog/CKFinder-3-Package-for-Laravel-released/)). I want to integrate a CKEditor in my Laravel project. Is there any official CKEditor package for Laravel?

Comment: As ckeditor is a markup editor in your browser (frontend), which functionality do you expect to get from a Laravel (backend) package? Because just installing the editor makes you able to receive the string in the Request object just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an editor which you can integrate with your Laravel project.
[Here is the link](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor)

There is also a clear documentation for that in there README.md